# how to search for OCaml functions by name and type

Tags: ocaml, tooling

In Haskell, there are two main ways to look up information on functions.

1. Sites like [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/).  These sites provide two main types of searching:

   1. Searching for the name of a function.  For example, [here is a search on Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=catMaybes) for a function called `catMaybes`.

      This search returns the type of the `catMaybes` function, as well as the package and module it is defined in.

      The major use-case for this type of search is when you see a function used somewhere and you want to know its type and what package it is defined in.
   2. Searching for the type of a function.  For example, [here is a search on Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+%5BMaybe+a%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) for a function of type `[Maybe a] -> [a]`.

      This search returns multiple functions that have a similar type, the first of which is `catMaybes`.  It also returns the package and module `catMaybes` is defined in.

      The major use-case for this type of search occurs when you are writing code.  You know the type of the function you need, and you're wondering if it is already defined somewhere.  For example, you have a list of `Maybe`s, and you want to return a list with all the `Nothing`s removed.  You know the function is going to have the type `[Maybe a] -> [a]`.
2. Directly from `ghci`.  In `ghci`, it is easy to get information about a function with the `:info` command, as long as the function is already in your environment.

   For example, here is a `ghci` session showing how to get info about the `catMaybes` function.  Note how you must import the `Data.Maybes` module first:

   ```
   > import Data.Maybe
   > :info catMaybes
   catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]   -- Defined in ‘Data.Maybe’
   >
   ```

   `:info` shows both the type of the `catMaybes` and where it is defined.

---

In OCaml, **what sites/tools** can be used to search for functions by **name or type**?

For example, I'm reading through [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/).  I came across [some code](https://github.com/realworldocaml/examples/blob/c67410726b8e00e7b78ab39edfebbcd8062048be/code/files-modules-and-programs-freq-median/freq.ml#L8-L11) using the `|>` function.  I wondered if there was a function `<|` for composing the opposite way.  However, I don't know of any way of searching for a function called `<|`.  Also, I don't know of any way of figuring out where `|>` is defined.

Based on the [linked code above](https://github.com/realworldocaml/examples/blob/c67410726b8e00e7b78ab39edfebbcd8062048be/code/files-modules-and-programs-freq-median/freq.ml), I guess the `|>` would either have to be in Pervasives or somewhere in Jane Street's Core, but it would be nice to have a tool that gave the exact location.

Comment: IIRC, [merlin](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/wiki) can show you where the functions you are using are defined (including builtins). However, I am not aware of a search

Answer (score 10, accepted):

awesome-ocaml has [a section on dev tools](https://github.com/rizo/awesome-ocaml#developer-tools) that should be helpful.

- [ocamloscope](https://ocamloscope.herokuapp.com/) ([github](https://github.com/camlspotter/ocamloscope.2)) is sort of an Hoogle for OCaml. Search by name works well. Search by type is less good.
- For local search by name, [ocp-browser](https://www.typerex.org/ocp-index.html#ocp-browser) provides a convenient TUI.
- In your editor, merlin and ocp-index can do lookup-to-definition and lookup-documentation.
- There is a WIP public instance of odig [here](http://docs.mirage.io/) with a lot (but not all) packages. You can use [odig](http://erratique.ch/software/odig) locally too, as stated in another answer.

P.S. The function you are looking for is `@@`, and it's in the standard library.

Comment: ocamloscope has been down for years. There is https://camlspotter.github.io/ocamloscope.html but it doesn't actually seem to function :,(

Answer (score 5):

The [ocp-index](https://www.typerex.org/ocp-index.html) package provides a basic facility for searching API functions, e.g.,

```
$ ocp-index locate '|>'
/home/ivg/.opam/devel/build/ocaml/stdlib/pervasives.ml:39:0
```

The [ocp-browser](https://www.typerex.org/ocp-index.html#ocp-browser) is a beautiful interface to this utility.

They are all integrated with Emacs (and other popular text editors). Speaking of text editors and IDE, [Merlin](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin) is a killer feature without which I can't imagine OCaml coding anymore. It is capable of jumping directly to the definition, extracting documentation and incremental typechecking.

Speaking of web-based search, there was an [argot](http://argot.x9c.fr/) document generator that has an API search engine featuring type search, full-text search, and regular expressions. A project is somewhat abandoned and doesn't work with the latest OCaml.

We [forked](https://github.com/ivg/argot/tree/1.2-devel) it, update to the latest OCaml, fixed a few bugs, and enhanced the unification procedure to get a better type search. The result can be found [here](http://binaryanalysisplatform.github.io/bap/api/v1.1.0/argot_index.html).

One of the main features is a search by type manifest, that ignores such irrelevant things as parameter ordering in functions, field names, differences between record names and tuples (e.g., `string * int` is the same as `{name : string; age : int}`) and aliasing. For example, in our project there are quite a few aliases, e.g., `type bil = stmt list = Stmt.t list = Stmt.t Core_kernel.Std.list = ...`. You can choose any name when you search (using type manifest), as the algorithm will correctly unify all aliases.

Answer (score 3):

[odig](https://github.com/dbuenzli/odig)  may be helpful. once installed, you can browse by package and by function.